# Maximal arrangements of $3 \times 3n$ arrays with $0$-$1$ entries

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Let $n$ be a large positive integer and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of $3 \times 3n$ matrices with entries in the set $\{0,1\}$ such that each row sums up to $n$ and

$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=kn+1}^{(k+1)n} a_{ij} = n$$

for $k = 0,1,2$ (this last condition says that if we divide the array into three $3 \times n$ rectangles, each should have $n$ ones in them). Define a function $\rho : \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ by

$$\displaystyle \rho(A, B) = \sum_{i = 1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^{3n} \min\{a_{ij}, b_{ij}\}.$$

Observe that the summand in the sum above is non-zero if and only if $a_{ij} = b_{ij} = 1$.

We say a subset
$$\mathcal{S} = \left\{A^{(1)}, \cdots, A^{(k)} \right\}$$

of $\mathcal{A}$ is *good* if for every $1 \leq i < j \leq k$ we have

$$\displaystyle \rho \left(A^{(i)}, A^{(j)} \right) =n. $$

Is there a way to estimate the maximum size of a good subset $\mathcal{S}$, as a function of $n$?

Comment: You can consider the graph with vertex set $\mathcal A$ and edges given by $\rho = n$. This is a regular graph, and it should be possible to write down its number of vertices and degree. There should be results on the size of a maximal clique.

Comment: I'm not sure that the graph is still regular after the second condition is added, but I'd expect the vertex degree not to vary by much. In any case, I'm not an expert in graph theory, so I can't really tell if this interpretation helps.

Comment: For what it's worth: when $n = 1$, one has permutation matrices, and the graph is a $K_{3,3}$, so the maximal good subsets are of size two. When $n = 2$, the set $\mathcal A$ has size 534, and the graph has degrees 177 (144 times), 186 (384 times) and 195 (6 times).

Comment: Does this problem come from somewhere?

Comment: @SamHopkins yes, it is a toy version of a problem I am working on